# Swift MacOS application window size did change?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I need to change main view content depending on view orientation. If user changed the size of view from Landscape to portrait I need to change main view.
How to detect using swift that MacOS application main view size did changed and get new size?

Comment: GeometryReader?

Comment: ViewThatFits might be an option or SwiftUI.Layout

Comment: Note `ViewThatFits` is available since macOS 13.0, but that may be a little too new for the installed user base, at least at this moment in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @jnpdx comment I created solution:

```
#if os(macOS)
enum UserInterfaceSizeClass {
    case compact
    case regular
}
#endif

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var verticalSizeClass = UserInterfaceSizeClass.regular
    @State var horizontalSizeClass = UserInterfaceSizeClass.regular

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Subview()
                .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, horizontalSizeClass)
                .environment(\.verticalSizeClass, verticalSizeClass)
                .onChange(of: geometry.size) { size in
                    updateSizeClasses(size: size)
                }
        }
    }

    private func updateSizeClasses(size: CGSize) {
        // Some logic updated SizeClasses IF NEED
    }
}
```

Comment: `UserInterfaceSizeClass` is in macOS since 10.15.  Try `if #available(macOS 10.15, *) {...`  instead of `#if os`.